# Select few Dictionary Keys from list of dictionaries while also adding new keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I want to select few of the keys from the existing list of dictionary and also add few other keys by looking up into another map.

main list is as follows

```
result=[{'key1':123,'key2':'prod','key3':'abc','key4':'cde'},{'key1':123,'key2':'prod','key3':'def','key4':'qrs'},{'key1':321,'key2':'sale','key3':'dssd','key4':'cfde'}]
```

Keys Needed in new list as follows,`key5` and `key6`  being new keys which need to be added

```
wantedkeys=['key1','key3','key5','key6']
```

Dictionary Used for adding new key values

```
keyMap={(123, 'key5'): 'abc', (123, 'key6'): 'pqr'}
```

I'm able to select `key1` and `key3` to get the output using below syntax.

```
new_list = [{ key: record[key]  for key in wantedkeys } for record in result if record['key2']=='prod']
```

but while extending this to also add the additional keys I'm getting syntax error.

```
new_list = [{ key : keyMap[record['key1'],key] if key in ['key5','key6'] else  key: record[key]  for key in wantedkeys } for record in result if record['key2']=='Prod']
```

I know this could be done by looping over the list , but is there more pythonic way to achieve this  with better performance as my list will have few million records
any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please do not include an answer in your question. This is misleading for others - it is not immediately visible the question was answered when browsing through the site. Extract it and answer your question directly (you can even score points through that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Hope this will be helpful

```
new_list = [dict({ key: record[key]  for key in ['key1','key3']},key5=keyMap[record['key1'],'key5'],key6=keyMap[record['key1'],'key6']) for record in result if record['key2']=='prod']
```